# Raspberry pi pico usb debbuging on Windows

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, putty, minicom, raspberry-pi-pico

I recently bought raspberry pi pico and I follow the How to get started with raspberry pico in C/C++ tutorial, but I have only windows computer. I want to debug my pico with usb. I compiled the example hello world project with cmake usb configuration (as shown in [tutorial](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf)) and draged a usb/hello_usb.uf2 file to pico. Also there is a elf file *for debugger*, but I have no idea, what to do with it. Only thing about connecting pico usb stdout to computer, that I found in tutorials and datasheets is this command for minicom:

```
$ minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0
```

Unfortunately minicom is only available for Linux, but I found out what different parts of that command means:

1. Port: /dev/ttyACM0
2. Baud rate: 115200
3. -o means that minicom doesn't initial setup (I don't exactly know what it is)

And I tried to enter these informations to puTTY:

[image: putty serial config]

I tried a lot of other combinations of values that are not specified in that command (On screenshot is config for some arduino board, that I found), but I always just heard windows fail tone. All stuff I do and describe here might be wrong, I am a beginner, but I didn't found a good source of information about this.

Should I use something else (not puTTY)?

EDIT:

I got it! I did some mistakes during sdk setup and tinyUSB didn't work, so I couldn't even see pico in device manager. I did the whole setup again and everything works now. I also found video, how to connect pico via putty: https://youtu.be/BjGc60Mmwz8 . Also as aMike said, you have to type just com port to puTTY, not /dev/ttyACM0.

Comment: Your serial line on Windows will be something like COM3: or COM4: or whatever name Windows gave it. Part way down this page, it explains serial port names for macos, Linux, and Windows: https://www.twilio.com/blog/programming-raspberry-pi-pico-microcontroller-micropython  Yes, it's for micropython, but it explains the serial ports, that's all I was going for. For your putty setup - everything looks good, except you need a COM#: port.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thats not really debugging. Putty is just a serial monitor for getting `printf()` from your Pico device. For real debugging abilities (breakpoints, variable watch etc..) and to understand how those `.elf` files work, check this [project](https://github.com/xenois/pico-dev).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you now actually get debug capabilities/ are runtime errors printed to putty?

I can't get it to work, the Pico just stops working if there is an error. I turned exceptions on in the CMakeLists.txt, that did allow me to write try catch statements, but try catch doesn't seem to work.
I am almost giving up and going back to Micropython. But FreeRTOS has way better multitask capabilities.